# To get started with visual programming

Tags: python, data-visualization

I am unfamiliar with visual programming. I am writing a program now. I want to show the data my program produces in another visualization program. For example, using a dynamic diagram to show my data, etc. To learn visualization program, what do I have to learn or if there any tools to be  recommended? (preferably python related)

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of very useful libraries available, choosing which would depend on what you want to achieve specifically. An example of a well supported, general python library that has lots of functionality and visual programming tools is [plotly](https://plot.ly/python/). Although I suggest you do some more research.